# Magento duplicates SKU in file export by DataFlow Export

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise

I use the DataFlow **Import/Export** for updating product information. But now I am getting duplicates SKU in file results when I try to export product

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Do the duplicates exist in the database?

Comment: In data base in fine.
I just log sku in product collection and everything is good. Some thing wrong in export code.
Help me please. thank you.

Comment: I have no clue about Dataflow. What about using importExport?

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/baconl/Magento-1.9.2.1-duplicate-sku-fix Its a temporary fix until the magento core team fixes it,

Answer (score 0):

When you update to Magento 1.9.2.X you will have this problem. If you use the `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Parser/Products.php` from a older version of Magento it will fix your problem.

You can try using this link, its a temporary fix that uses a older `Products.php` file:

https://github.com/baconl/Magento-1.9.2.1-duplicate-sku-fix

Keep in mind, this is a temporary fix until the magento core team fixes it in the next version of Magento.